# Power Automate: Using "Wait for image" and "Extract text with OCR" in unattended mode possible?

Tags: power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I want to automate a Webswing session to run in unattended mode. Webswing is a web server that allows applications to run within the web browser. So there is no access to UI elements that the bot could access.

Therefore, I initially worked with image recognition (e.g., using the "Wait for image" and "Extract text with OCR" actions) in attended mode. Now I would like to switch to unattended mode. Does anyone have experience with this and know if the image recognition actions in a session like Webswing can be applied to unattended robots or are there other commands I can use for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, however it is worth keeping in mind that the [screen size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/how-to/image-recognition-screen-resolution) needs to be set to the size you run the flow in when attended.

See: [how to set screen resolution unattended mode](https://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/)